# Pass props to props.history.push('path') in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application

**BACKGROUND**

I am attempting to learn ReactJS by building my first Single Page Application. I usually work in .NET MVC, and I'm coming across some difficulties in the thought process required for SPAs. Anyways, I am using the latest version of React & React Router. Here is what I have at the moment.

[image: my app UI]

**CODE**

So far, I have **5 true components** in total. Here they are in order of usage:

1. App
2. ArtistList

   > Loops over artist array (coming from a local variable so far) and draws Artistcards
3. ArtistCard
4. Artist

   > Think of this as the detailed view of an artist. You get here by clicking an ArtistCard (shown in screenshot) so that you can see the list of LyricCards
5. LyricCard

My routes are declared in my [App component]. Here is the JSX for that.

```
<div className="App">
  <Header />
  <Route exact path="/" render={routeProps => <ArtistList {...routeProps} artists={artists} />} />
  <Route exact path="/artist/:artistUrlName" component={Artist} />
</div>
```

Here is the **code for my [ArtistList component]**:

```
class ArtistList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="artist-list">
        {this.props.artists.map(artist =>
          <ArtistCard key={artist.imageUrl} artist={artist} history={this.props.history} />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the **code for my [ArtistCard component]**:

```
class ArtistCard extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.navigateToArtist = this.navigateToArtist.bind(this);
  }
  navigateToArtist() {
    this.props.history.push(`/artist/${this.props.artist.urlFriendlyName}`);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className="artist-card"
        onClick={() => {
          this.navigateToArtist();
        }}
      >
        <div className="artist-image">
          <img src={this.props.artist.imageUrl} alt="artist" />
        </div>
        <div className="artist-name">
          <h3>
            {this.props.artist.name}
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div className="artist-meta">
          <div className="artist-lyrics">
            <h4>
              {this.props.artist.lyricsCount}
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div className="artist-hearts">
            <h4>
              {this.props.artist.likesCount}
            </h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**PROBLEM**

When clicking an artist card (e.g. James Brown), I am able to navigate to the route `/artist/james-brown`, but I don't know how I can pass the data (the props) required by the [Artist component] (which will show a list of lyric cards).

As mentioned, this is my first ever SPA, and I am not sure if I'm going about this the right way. As a developer, I know I can grab the `urlFriendlyName` from the URL and pass that to an API endpoint that would get me a list of the lyrics (and other stuff I may need), and I can then set those on the `state` of the component via one a relevant component life-cycle mount method.

But is that the way with SPAs? I mean another way I can do this would be to make a single call to the API endpoint in my controller / parent [App component] and get all artists and their lyrics and everything else I need? I'll still need you to tell me how I can then pass the artist data and all his/her lyrics via props to the [Artist component].

Comment: There are few ways to go about it - 1) The child components stay with the parent but hidden initially, when you click on the card toggle the visibiity of corresponding card. This can get complicated. 2) Pass down the props to the route itself using render prop, check this for more details - https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4105 3) Use redux and fetch the child components state on of the lifecycle events.

Comment: you said 'the ArtistList array Loops over artist array (coming from a local variable so far) and draws Artistcards',

 you can pass the the artist in the array as props to the Artistcards. like <Artistcards artist={artistInTheArray}>. then you can access the artist inside `Artistcards` component using `this.props.artist`

Comment: can you also share what ArtistList component looks like.

Comment: Thanks @Akhil, I'll have a read. abdul, I've added the code